# Postfix bouncing valid emails

Tags: domain, postfix, hosts, virtual-host, lamp

I've installed postfix on a lamp stack with multiple vhosts, with a the below configuration:

```
myhostname = myserver.home
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = myserver.home, domain1.co.uk, localhost.home, localhost, domain2.com, 
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

When I tested it I can email out using the command line, however postfix is bouncing back all inbound emails with the error message:

```
<recipient1_domain1@mail.myserver.home> (expanded from <recipient1@domain1.co.uk>): Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=mail.myserver.home type=AAAA: Host not found
```

Originally I thought this was a DNS/UFW issue but I can see the received emails are being logged on the local server and then bounced when it can't find the host/domain on the server itself.

I'm fairly new to webhosting and this is my first attempt at a mail server so I think it's a fairly simple mistake I've made, but I think the problem might be related to postfix converting recipient1_domain1@mail.myserver.home format, and then not being able to find the correct alias due to hashing.

Any info on what's going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you have in /etc/aliases and /etc/postfix/virtual?

Comment: Do you see more errors in `/var/log/maillog`? Take a look though the answers here for some related troubleshooting steps: https://serverfault.com/questions/960456/postfix-name-service-error-for-name-domain-com-type-mx-host-not-found-try-aga

Comment: In /etc/aliases contains, just 'postmaster' and 'root'

In /etc/postfix/virtual, there's 4 hosts in the format `admin@domain.com admin_host`

There isn't a file `/var/log/maillog`; there's is however a `/var/log/mail.log` which is showing that the inbound emails pointing to the correct address/Mx record. But generates this: `to=<recipient_domain@mail.myserver.home>, orig_to=<recipeient@domain.com>, relay=none, delay=0.17, delays=0.15/0.01/0.01/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=mail.myserver.home type=AAAA: Host not found)`

Comment: try setting `myhostname = mail.myserver.home`. It looks like your MX record might point to the `mail.myserver.home` hostname, which is not listed anywhere in `myhostname` or `mydestination` and gets bounced. Check `nslookup -q=mx domain1.co.uk`